# Internal speakers on my laptop are dead, but external speakers don't get engaged either; any fixes?

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I have a Dell-precision laptop with Ubuntu #14-04 installed. My internal speakers got broken (producing highly distorted sound), and a few day ago simply died (no sound at all). I tried to use external speakers using a round jack on my laptop, but got no sound either. My expectation was that external speakers can simply  over-ride the internal ones, no matter what, but I can see now that I was wrong. What can I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it turned out it is a very common trouble with ubuntu. What I learnt, a greatly useful command to find out what is wrong are "alsamixer" and "aplay -l"; they would give the status of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices. The latter one produced a response:

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

ALSA lib conf.c:635:(get_char_skip_comments) Cannot access file filename

ALSA lib conf.c:1686:(snd_config_load1) *toplevel*:4:10:No such file or directory

ALSA lib conf.c:3406:(config_file_open) /home/(myID)/  may be old or corrupted: consider to remove or fix it

ALSA lib conf.c:3328:(snd_config_hooks_call) function snd_config_hook_load returned error: No such file or directory

ALSA lib conf.c:3777:(snd_config_update_r) hooks failed, removing configuration

The offending file appeared to be ".asoundrc" in my home directory; pretty long one. My friend from Canada suggested to start with just removing it (renaming, just in case) and see what happened after I reboot the comp. It worked like a charm: the sound was back, loud and clear, both from internal and external speakers. I still don't know what is/was the function of that file; but my comp didn't bother to put in anything to replace it. For my own education, I'll later on find a good one in the internet, and try to see what it can add to the the proper functioning of speakers.

Comment: Now the question is how a "pretty long" `.asoundrc` suddenly appeared in your home directory without you noticing it ...

Comment: @dirkt -- interesting; thanks... Are you implying  that it was a unfriendly  piece of soft placed there as possibly a practical joke...  Hmm... this is a "dot" file, and I don't use "ls -a" command too often.... Should be looking  now for other "jokes"...

Comment: I have really no idea. The options range from "you made some typo and don't remember it, so it's your own fault" to "some of the programs you are running have bugs" to "you have some strange sort of virus" (unlikely). The contents of the `.asoundrc` may give a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating Audio drivers.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS

or else its some hardware mistake.

Comment: thanks! I did that . I followed the first step, "Make sure dkms package is installed by running command: "sudo apt-get install dkms" , and installed dkms; no hitches.    But the next instruction was  "Go to this page", which left me lost; which "this page"?  Without that "page" I cannot perform any of the next instructions, such as e, g. "You will find a table under the "Packages" heading. Look for the "Series" column and locate the package corresponding to your distribution series (Precise, Trusty, Xenial etc)....", etc. Can you help to decipher what is "this page"?

Comment: "This Page" is  :- https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily/+packages

Comment: Aneesh: I downloaded a pkg, and my new troubles began. My comp reports "Error in system programming", and my VLC shows that the system produces  only  "Dummy output", i. e. I hear nothing. How I can delete that package competently?  Are you sure that those files suggested by you are not a half-done product, or worse -- a malicious product? How can I switch my system back to at least its initial stage, or to regular, not "dummy" output ?

Comment: well... It worked fine for me. Anyways, its better to remove package if it causes any problems. Open **Ubuntu Software Center** (you will find that in System dropdown menu > Administration) and click the dropdown menu next to **Installed** button. There you can see the software packages you installed. Click the _package name_ you and click remove. (or in terminal `apt-get remove <package_name>` ).

Comment: And here is one more link http://askubuntu.com/questions/457619/sound-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04 if you wish to troubleshoot more. I haven't checked this one.